# Phonon modes and atom vibrations vs temperature

Tags: temperature, vibrations, phonons

My understanding is that number of phonon modes depends on the number of atoms in a system and will be gradually populated with increasing temperature until Debye temperature. At the same time, atoms also oscillate around their equilibrium positions, and the magnitudes of the vibrations increase with temperature. My question is does the atom vibrations and phonon modes have any correlation with each other? If so, what happens after Debye temperature? The atom vibrations still increase with temperature but the phonon modes are already mostly populated. Are there any good textbooks or youtube lectures on this topic? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The phonon modes *are* the atomic vibrations. In a semi-classical picture, the amplitude of the atomic vibrations is related to the number of excitations populating each phonon mode. Etc. I feel like *any* good solid state physics book covers this in some detail.